# Pass xml serialized object from Silverlight Client side to Server side

Tags: asp.net, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, xml-serialization

I need to pass xml serialized data from a Silverlight application Client side to the server side (asp.net). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I do it using Mike Talbott's Silverlight serializer: http://whydoidoit.com/silverlight-serializer/  You'll just need to keep the classes you want to serialized in separate assemblies - have one for Silverlight and one for .Net and make sure the names of the dll's are the same.

Comment: I did it with a custom HttpHandler. I use it like a middle-ware between my Silverlight view and the aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an WCF service with a method on your server side and send the xml as text or BASE64 encoded to the method.